# Deal with a URL having variable number of segments and contains a keyword text in route mapping

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, url, pattern-matching

I am writing below code to map the route for URLs having a a keyword  named "Listing-Filter" anywhere in the URL in my asp.net MVC application like below -

```
routes.MapRoute(
              name: "Core_ListingPage",
               url: "{pageUrl}",
                defaults: new {controller = "ListingPage", action = "Page" },
               constraints: new { pageUrl = @"^(.listing-filter.)?$" }
                      ).DataTokens.Add("area", "community");
```

It have not worked so I suspected my Regex expression and replaced it with full page URL like below just to check that constraints are working or not  -

```
routes.MapRoute(
              name: "Core_ListingPage",
               url: "{pageUrl}",
                defaults: new {controller = "ListingPage", action = "Page" },
               constraints: new { pageUrl = /home/items/kichen/listing-filter/price-range-25-to-100/price-range-100-to-200" }
                      ).DataTokens.Add("area", "community");
```

But it is also not working and I am concluding that something wrong with either in the URL or constraints parameter.  Could somebody  help me on that.

NOTE - Below is something I want to achieve this routing code and any different approach will also be appreciated.

**Any  URL  with variable number of segments  which contains  “listing-filter” text should be handled by this  route mapping.**

Thanks a lot  in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression needs to be changed to match an entire URL. This should work:

```
@"^.+listing-filter.+$"
```

The `+` after the `.` will match one or more of any character, instead of just matching one character like you originally had.

Also, I took out the capture group `()` and the zero or one `?` modifier since they are not necessary.